# How to append multiple text lines followed by a single <br> tag when generating html with Python

Tags: python, html

I am trying to generate an html object using Python's py._xmlgen's html class. In this html I want to place a 
 after each line of text.

The problem is that when running this code

```
from py._xmlgen import html

if __name__ == '__main__':
    br_standalone = html.br('some text between br tags')
    div_standalone = html.div('some more text between div tags')
    print(br_standalone)
    print(div_standalone)

    div_with_br = div_standalone
    div_with_br.append(br_standalone)
    print(div_with_br)
```

I get this output:

```html
<br>some text between br tags</br>
<div>some more text between div tags</div>
<div>some more text between div tags<br>some text between br tags</br></div>
```

Which if you'll "Run code snippet" and inspect the result html below, you will see that the closing  is also rendered as 2nd line break. So, for each html.br I get 2 line breaks, instead of a single line break.

How can I get the output to have just a single br tag for each html.br I use?

Comment: A workaround to this is to use html.div instead of html.br . It's an ugly solution, but it generates the look I need.

Comment: Br tags shouldn't have content inside them

Comment: So appending an empty html.br('') should do the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [user3080953](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080953/user3080953)'s comment: "br tags shouldn't have content inside them", I modified the code.

In order to get a single br tag after the text, use the following empty tag:

```
br_standalone = html.br()
```

So, when using the following code:

```
from py._xmlgen import html

if __name__ == '__main__':
    div1 = html.div(class_='multiline_div')
    div1.append('text line #1')
    div1.append(html.br())
    div1.append('text line #2')
    div1.append(html.br())
    print(div1)
```

I got the following html:

```html
<div class="multiline_div">
   text line #1<br/>
   text line #2<br/>
</div>
```

Please note an additional finding here, that you can also append to the html.div plain text, followed by appending a br tag, to create multi lines text within the div tag.